# apitest.cybersource.com new key failure

Tags: cybersource

All new keys created in https://ebc2test.cybersource.com/ebc2/ result in failure response:

{
"response": {
"rmsg": "Authentication Failed"
}
}

Reproduction Steps:

1. Create new Cybersource Test Account here: https://developer.cybersource.com/api/developer-guides/dita-gettingstarted/registration.html
2. Receive email & set up user
3. Generate new REST API Shared Secret Key
4. Attempt to use key here: https://developer.cybersource.com/api-reference-assets/index.html#payments_payments_process-a-payment

Key Generation (note - this is a merchant id based off todays date)
[Cybersource Key Generation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/abY4m.png)

And a request failing
[Failed Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aESk5.png)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the Merchant ID is correct

you can get the Merchant ID from the EBC Dashboard